# How to retrieve list of integers in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I send a list of Ids to a stored procedure and would like to `INSERT/UPDATE` them into a table and receive a list of Ids that weren't `INSERTED/UPDATED` so I could display a detailed error to the user.

How can I accomplish it in this stored procedure?

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[NET_SET_Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds_ExpirePriorityByIds]    
   (@IdsList NumericList READONLY)    
AS 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds]    
    SET PromotionExpirationDate = DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE())
    WHERE IDS IN (SELECT * FROM @IdsList)

    IF (@@ERROR != 0)
       RETURN -1;
```

Comment: Your `update` will either fully work or it won't. It will never update half of the ID's and then fail in the middle with an error. If there are 10 ID's in your list and they all exist in the target table then they will either ALL be updated or NONE will be updated if there is some kind of database error (i.e. a check constraint on `PromotionExpiryDate` or a trigger on the table that throws an error). Are you trying to catch database errors or business logic errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create function that will return table with the missing ids-something like that-**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [NET_SET_Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds_ExpirePriorityByIds]    
   (@IdsList NumericList READONLY)    
RETURNS  @rtnTable TABLE 
(
    -- columns returned by the function
   IDS int) 
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE [dbo].[Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds]    
    SET PromotionExpirationDate = DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE())
    WHERE IDS IN (SELECT * FROM @IdsList)
    GO 
    insert into @rtnTable
    select IDS from @IdsList x
    where not exists (select * 
                  [Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds]  P 
                  where P.IDS = x.IDS)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean IDs in that list that didn't exist in the table? Assuming your field is called IDS in the parameter too, this does it:

```
select IDS from @IdsList L 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from [dbo].[Int_PriorityAccountsForXMLFeeds] P 
                  where P.IDS = L.IDS)
```

Comment: If I send 10 IDS and only 9 got 'INSERTED/UPDATED'  then i would like to get the ID that didn't. Your answer covers other scenario that some of the IDS don't exist which i can use, but not what i meant.

Comment: Your procedure doesn't even insert anything, but if it's supposed to insert the ones it didn't update, then it must be a case of an error? For that, checking what the value of PromotionExpirationDate is, and fetch rows based on that might work

Comment: In case of an Error i would like to get the IDS that weren't UPDATED. I have another stored procedure that INSERT IDS and i would like to get for it the IDS that weren't INSERTED. Till today , i used to get the error by how many rows were affected. If i sent 10 and only 9 were updated i got 9 and i could tell the user that not all the IDS were UPDATED/INSERTED.  Now i want to know which IDS were not affected.